# Random values, only duplicates excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

i wanna make a sheet with random duplicates, column A will have 100 rows, in this column, will be blank rows, but will be a name let s say "John" which will be repeted in percent of 10% from 100rows.. But i will need another sheet with an percent of 5%.

Where to start?
I tried with rand, randbetween but i can t put the percentage with repeted duplicate (10/100)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAYOb.jpg

Comment: Are you trying to have it statistically produce John 10% of the time? Or do you want it to always have exactly 10 occurrences of John out of 100 trials? If it's the second one, you're looking for a random permutation, not random values.

Comment: Not clear at all. `=IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,10) = 1, "John","")` would seem to do what you want -- on one of the many possible interpretations of what it is that you actually want. Please clarify. It would help if you show some of your attempts, since that would give a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, added a photo, in 100 rows i need to have 10 duplicate value, random, everytime i acces the file, will be random positions for my value "John", but the condition match 10% of 100 rows maximum must contain name "John", if you need i can provide more details

Comment: Tried with if and randbetween, it s ok but i don t have the criteria 10% of 100rows must be with "John". If i refresh, sometimes i have 7... 12.. 10. I need to have exactly 10 of 100 rows with value John

Comment: Put exactly 10 "John"s in an array of 100 and then shuffle it.

Comment: How to do that? I don t understand sorry

Comment: The answer that Mr. Coleman gave will work perfectly. Here is an example of "shuffle": In Column A1 to A100 put the RAND() function. In Column B1 to B100 type ten "Johns"s as he stated. It matters not which rows you put them in. Highlight the range A1 to B100 and the use "Sort and Filter" to sort Column A ( the random numbers). The "Johns" will be randomly distributed in Column B each time you do this. He gave a simple, yet excellent solution to this.